# Convert Encryption Java code into Go code

Tags: java, go, encryption

I have following java code that does encryption and decryption using RSA Public and Private keys.

I wrote similar code in GO to do the same.

But when I try to decrypt a string using Go code that was encrypted in Java code, I see error:
crypto/rsa: decryption error

```java
public class EncryptDecryptUtil {

    private static final String MODE = "RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding";
    private static EncryptDecryptUtil single_instance = null;

    public static EncryptDecryptUtil getInstance()
    {
        if (single_instance == null)
            single_instance = new EncryptDecryptUtil();
        return single_instance;
    }

    public static String encryptText(String text, String keyStr) throws Exception {
        String resultText = null;
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            Key publicKey = getRSAPublicFromPemFormat(keyStr);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE, "BC");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            resultText = new String(Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes())));
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultText;
    }

    public static String decryptText(String text, String keyStr) throws Exception {
        String resultText = null;
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            Key privateKey = getRSAPrivateFromPemFormat(keyStr);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE, "BC");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            resultText = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(text.getBytes())));

        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultText;
    }

    private static PrivateKey getRSAPrivateFromPemFormat(String keyStr) throws Exception {
        return (PrivateKey) getKeyFromPEMString(keyStr, data -> new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(data), (kf, spec) -> {
            try {
                return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot generate PrivateKey from String : " + keyStr + e);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    private static PublicKey getRSAPublicFromPemFormat(String keyStr) throws Exception {
        return (PublicKey) getKeyFromPEMString(keyStr, data -> new X509EncodedKeySpec(data), (kf, spec) -> {
            try {
                return kf.generatePublic(spec);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot generate PublicKey from String : " + keyStr + e);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    private static Key getKeyFromPEMString(String key, Function<byte[], EncodedKeySpec> buildSpec,
                                         BiFunction<KeyFactory, EncodedKeySpec, ? extends Key> getKey) throws Exception {
        try {
            // Read PEM Format
            PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(key));
            PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
            pemReader.close();

            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            return getKey.apply(kf, buildSpec.apply(pemObject.getContent()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

```golang
package encryption

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/sha512"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

// Encrypt encrypts string with public key
func Encrypt(msg string, publicKeyFilePath string) (string, error) {
    pubKey, err := ReadPublicKey(publicKeyFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    encrypted, err := encrypt([]byte(msg), pubKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    base64Encoded := base64.URLEncoding.WithPadding(61).EncodeToString(encrypted)
    return base64Encoded, nil
}

// Decrypt decrypts string with private key
func Decrypt(msg string, privateKeyFilePath string) (string, error) {
    privKey, err := ReadPrivateKey(privateKeyFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    base64Decoded, err := base64.URLEncoding.WithPadding(61).DecodeString(msg)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    decrypted, err := decrypt(base64Decoded, privKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(decrypted), nil
}

// GenerateKeyPair generates a new key pair
func GenerateKeyPair(bits int) (*rsa.PrivateKey, *rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    privkey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, bits)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("Error generating Key Pair: %s", err)
    }
    return privkey, &privkey.PublicKey, nil
}

// ReadPublicKey reads public key from a file
func ReadPublicKey(publicKeyFile string) (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    pubPemData, err := ioutil.ReadFile(publicKeyFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error [%s] reading public key from file: %s", err, publicKeyFile)
    }
    return BytesToPublicKey(pubPemData)
}

// ReadPrivateKey reads private key from a file
func ReadPrivateKey(privateKeyFile string) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    privKeyData, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privateKeyFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error [%s] reading private key from file: %s", err, privateKeyFile)
    }
    return BytesToPrivateKey(privKeyData)
}

// PrivateKeyToBytes private key to bytes
func PrivateKeyToBytes(priv *rsa.PrivateKey) []byte {
    privBytes := pem.EncodeToMemory(
        &pem.Block{
            Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
            Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(priv),
        },
    )

    return privBytes
}

// PublicKeyToBytes public key to bytes
func PublicKeyToBytes(pub *rsa.PublicKey) ([]byte, error) {
    pubASN1, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(pub)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error converting PublicKey to Bytes: %s", err)

    }

    pubBytes := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: pubASN1,
    })

    return pubBytes, nil
}

// BytesToPrivateKey bytes to private key
func BytesToPrivateKey(priv []byte) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    block, _ := pem.Decode(priv)

    enc := x509.IsEncryptedPEMBlock(block)
    b := block.Bytes
    var err error
    if enc {
        log.Println("is encrypted pem block")
        b, err = x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error decrypting PEM Block: %s", err)
        }
    }
    key, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error parsing PKCS1 Private Key: %s", err)
    }
    return key, nil
}

// BytesToPublicKey bytes to public key
func BytesToPublicKey(pub []byte) (*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    block, _ := pem.Decode(pub)

    enc := x509.IsEncryptedPEMBlock(block)
    b := block.Bytes
    var err error
    if enc {
        log.Println("is encrypted pem block")
        b, err = x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error decrypting PEM Block: %s", err)
        }
    }
    ifc, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error parsing PKCS1 Public Key: %s", err)
    }
    key, ok := ifc.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error converting to Public Key: %s", err)
    }
    return key, nil
}

// encrypt encrypts data with public key
func encrypt(msg []byte, pub *rsa.PublicKey) ([]byte, error) {
    hash := sha512.New()
    ciphertext, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(hash, rand.Reader, pub, msg, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error encrypting: %s", err)
    }
    return ciphertext, nil
}

// Decrypt decrypts data with private key
func decrypt(ciphertext []byte, priv *rsa.PrivateKey) ([]byte, error) {
    hash := sha512.New()
    plaintext, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(hash, rand.Reader, priv, ciphertext, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error decrypting: %s", err)
    }
    return plaintext, nil
}
```

How to make sure that value encrypted using java code is decrypted properly by Go code.

Comment: For starters, `sha512.New()` seems wrong since your Java code specifies SHA256.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It works now with sha256.New()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from @Michael, I changed go code to use sha256.New() instead of sha512.New() and that solved the issue. (Good catch!)
I am now able to encrypt in Java and decrypt in Go.